# Buscar una palabra en una matriz de caracteres y reemplazar dicha palabra en otra de ceros con "1"

Tags: java, matrices

El problema que tengo es crear dos matrices, una de caracteres y otra de ceros, y buscar una palabra en la matriz de caracteres. Cuando encuentre cada letra de esa palabra la sustituya con `1` en la matriz llena de ceros.

public class Buscar {

```
public static void main(String[]args){
    char [][] m1 = {{'h','p','r','q'},
                    {'k','o','ñ','s'},
                    {'s','n','l','j'},
                    {'u','g','e','a'}};

    int[][] m2 = {{0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0}};
}
```

}

Ya tengo mis matrices, en este caso necesito que me sustituya `hola` y se imprima así:

```
1  0  0  0

0  1  0  0

0  0  1  0

0  0  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

te dejo el código por aquí, espero que sirva de ayuda.

```
public class CambioNumeros {

//Se inicializan los vectores
private char[][] m1 ={{'h','p','r','q'},
        {'k','o','ñ','s'},
        {'s','n','l','j'},
        {'u','g','e','a'}};

private int[][] m2 = {{0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0},
      {0,0,0,0}};


/**
 * Identifica los caracteres del parametro y cambia los numeros en caso que sea verdadero.
 * @param texto es la cadena de caracteres
 */
public void cambiarNumeros(String texto) {

    //guarda los caracteres en un nuevo vector
    char[] matriztexto = texto.toCharArray();

    //recorren el array m1
    for(int fila=0; fila<m1.length; fila++) {
        for(int columna=0; columna<matriztexto.length; columna++) {

            //recorre el vector matriztexto
            for(int recorre=0; recorre<matriztexto.length; recorre++) {

                if(matriztexto[recorre]==m1[fila][columna]) {
                    m2[fila][columna]=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


/**
 * Muestra el array numerico
 */
public void mostrarMatrizNumeros() {
    for(int fila=0; fila<m2.length; fila++) {
        for(int col=0; col<m2.length; col++) {
            System.out.print(m2[fila][col]+" ");
        }
    System.out.println("");}
}

public static void main(String[]args) {
    CambioNumeros c = new CambioNumeros();
    c.cambiarNumeros("hola");
    c.mostrarMatrizNumeros();
}
```

}

Answer (score -3):

```
 public class HelloWorld{

  static  char [][] m1 = {{'h','p','r','q'},
                    {'k','o','ñ','s'},
                    {'s','n','l','j'},
                    {'u','g','e','a'}};

  static int[][] m2 = {{0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0}};

 public static void main(String []args){

     comparar('h');
      comparar('o');
       comparar('l');
        comparar('a');
        imprimir();

 }

 static void comparar(char valor){
     try{

         for(int i=0;i<m1.length;i++){
                      for(int j=0;j<m1.length;j++){
                           if(m1[i][j]==valor){
                               m2[i][j]=1;
                           }
                      }

                  }



     }catch(Exception e){

     }
 }


 static void imprimir(){
     try{
          for(int i=0;i<m2.length;i++){
              System.out.println();
              for(int j=0;j<m2.length;j++){
                  System.out.print(m2[i][j]);

              }

          }
     }
     catch(Exception r){

     }


 }
```

}

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez Por favor, lee [answer] y completa el [tour]. Lo que el otro usuario te está pidiendo es razonable: si compartes código sin ningún tipo de explicación ni comentario, es posible que los usuarios que lo vean no sepan qué es lo que hace o cómo funciona, por lo que no es de ayuda.